# When to use "faire des pieds et des mains" vs "sortir le grand jeu"

Tags: usage, nuance

We were having a conversation in German about Japanese Geishas, and I said:

> Ihr **zieht alle Register**, um die Aufmerksamkeit der Leute zu gewinnen, aber alle interessieren sich nur für die Geishas, stimmt's? Machen wir uns doch nichts vor – ihr habt kein einziges Kunststück im Repertoire, das mit ihren Darbietungen konkurrieren könnte ...

I was wondering how I'd express the same idea in French. This is where I'd have said:

> ≈ Vous **faites des pieds et des mains** pour attirer l’attention des gens, mais ils n’en ont tous que pour les geishas, c'est ça ? On doit se faire une raison, vous ne connaissez pas de tours suffisamment captivants pour rivaliser avec leurs performances...

{rather than}:

> Vous **sortez le grand jeu** pour attirer l’attention des gens, mais ...
>
> {or}: Vous **avez sorti le grand jeu** pour attirer l’attention des gens, mais ...

---

The expression "*alle Register ziehen*" literally means "*pull all (musical) registers*" and figuratively "*pull out all the stops*".

Although "*faire des pieds et des mains (pour ...)*" and "*sortir le grand jeu (pour ...)*" are indeed synonymous -- with the meaning of "*se démener dans un but précis*", I get the impression that they are nuanced and differ in usage. Here, the use of "*sortir le grand jeu*" sounds odd to me:

- "*Sortir le grand jeu*" seems to have a connotation of going so far as to do something impressive or extreme as a desperate measure or a last resort, and the efforts involved are only temporary or a one-off. As such, it is often coupled with *Passé Composé*.
- "*faire des pieds et des mains*", on the other hand, seems to entail  more continuous efforts, which makes it more suitable for use in this context.

Several expressions, including "*Sortir le grand jeu*", are suggested in dictionaries as equivalents of "*alle Register ziehen*" or "*pull out all the stops*", but curiously, "*faire des pieds et des mains*" is nowhere to be seen.

Answer (score 5):

There is a difference between the 2 phrases, they are not really synonyms:

*Faire des pieds et des mains* means to make a lot of efforts (not necessarily with material means - cf. infra) to have a favor or a priviledge. It can have a slightly negative connotation, as it may imply the person who does that goes a bit over the line and can become an annoyance to the persons they interact with.

Ex: *Cette maman a fait des pieds et des mains pour que son fils ait le premier rôle dans le spectacle de fin d'année: elle a harcelé l'instituteur de coups de fil, elle a fait répéter son fils tous les soirs, elle a même demandé un rendez-vous avec le directeur pour le persuader que son fils était le meilleur choix !*

*Sortir le grand jeu* means to use a lot of material means in order to impress someone (there can be some other objectives as well, but there is this idea of deploying impressive means).

Ex: *il a sorti le grand jeu pour sa demande en mariage: il a invité sa fiancée à Venise avec vol en première classe, hôtel 5 étoiles et dîner romantique dans un des meilleurs restaurants de la ville.*

Taking again this example for the comparison, it would be a bit awkward to say someone has "fait des pieds et des mains" for a marriage proposal: it would mean the groom-to-be harrassed his fiancée and repeatedly asked her to marry him until she finally gave in.

Comment: Great. 1) I used "faire des pieds et des mains" in this context to express the idea of "*going all out to get their attention, trying this and that and everything in between*". Is it better than "sortir le grand jeu"? 2) So, depending on what I have in mind, can the two expressions both be used here?